# JavaScript Regular Expression not matching <a> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match URLs with a tested Regex expression but when I use JavaScript to evaluate it returns false.

Here is my code:

```
var $regex = new RegExp("<a\shref=\"(\#\d+|(https?|ftp):\/\/[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\\(\\)]+)\"(\stitle=\"[^\"<>]+\")?\s?>|<\/a>");

var $test = new Array();
$test[0] = '<a href="http://www.nytimes.com/imagepages/2010/09/02/us/HURRICANE.html">';
$test[1] = '<a href="http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/38877306/ns/weather/%29;">';
$test[2] = '<a href="http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/38927104" title="dd" alt="dd">';
for(var i = 0; i < $test.length; i++)
{
    console.log($test[i]);
    console.log($regex.test($test[i]));
}
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Is it [Earl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Earl_%282010%29)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

**You need to escape backslashes.** Any character with a special meaning needs to be escaped with a backslash in the regular expression, and the backslash itself needs to be escaped in the string. Effectively, `\s` should be represented as `\\s` if you construct it with `new Regexp("\\s")`.

**You need to allow more characters in your URLs**. Currently you don't even allow `/` characters. I would propose a character class like `[^"]` to match everything after `http://`. (Escaping the `"` character when used in t a string will make it `[^\"]`.

**You're not taking `alt` attributes into account**. You only match `title` attributes, not `alt` attributes.

A working example:

```
// Ditch new Regex("...") in favour of /.../ because it is simpler.
var $regex = /<a\shref="(#\d+|(https?|ftp):\/\/[^"]+)"(\stitle="[^"]+")?(\salt="[^"]+")?|<\/a>/;

var $test = new Array();
$test[0] = '<a href="http://www.nytimes.com/imagepages/2010/09/02/us/HURRICANE.html">';
$test[1] = '<a href="http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/38877306/ns/weather/%29;">';
$test[2] = '<a href="http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/38927104" title="dd" alt="dd">';
for(var i = 0; i < $test.length; i++)
{
    console.log($test[i]);
    console.log($regex.test($test[i]));
}
```

All three examples match this regex.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape backslashes when creating regular expressions with new `RegExp()` since you pass a string and a backslash is also an escaping character for strings.

```
new RegExp("\s"); // becomes /s/
new RegExp("\\s"); // becomes /\s/
```

Or just write your regexp as literals.

```
var re = /\s/;
```

Also, if you want to match URL's, why take a whole HTML tag into account?
The following regexp would suffice:

```
var urlReg = /^(?:\#\dhttp|ftp):\/\/[\w\d\.-_]*\/[^\s]*/i;
// anything past the third / that's not a space, is valid.
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that.  Thanks for your help, that was my problem.  I've been staring at that expression for far too long trying to figure that out.  Much appreciated!